# Easiest way to remote into a Windows 7 laptop with no video capabilities?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdmi, remote-access, remote

My dear beloved laptop of 4 years's GPU is dead. It can no longer display video, even through VGA or HDMI. It can still log into Windows, and I am able to blindly use cmd.exe, Windows Explorer, and manipulate files. (Thanks keyboard shortcuts and [begrudgingly] Microsoft Narrator.)

I want to still reuse this laptop somehow. Assuming my laptop could produce an image for a remote display, **what would be the easiest way to set up a remote connection between this laptop and another Windows 7 machine blindly.**

Perhaps making an automated installation and configuration on a working computer and transferring it/running it ONCE on my ~dead one. I was nearly driven insane from my last encounter with Narrator.

> Details:
>
> ASUS G53SX-NH17
>
> Intel Core i7 2670QM (2.20 GHz)
>
> 8 GB Memory
>
> 500 GB HDD
>
> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560M (RIP)
>
> Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit

### Update

I attempted to do a remote login but for some reason either safe-mode with networking or my network card wasn't letting me connect to the internet. Just as I was going to order some USB solution the laptop came back to life just once more for me and I was able to do a full back up. I'm pretty sure that that was its last dutiful breath left and haven't touched it since.

Thank you for the ideas, even though I didn't need them in the end.

Comment: It isn't really "remote", but have you tried a USB to VGA/DVI/HDMI adapter or a USB monitor? If it doesn't work you can just return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Remote Desktop Connection (RDP) to remote into the laptop.

Server Admins often use RDP to connect to servers which have no keyboard, mouse or monitor attached to them. Even though the gpu is dead on your laptop, you can RDP and use it normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a steady hand, patience, meticulous organization skills, some money, and several hours to kill then you can certainly look into the feasibility of replacing the GPU.

Replacements can be found on eBay for $100-$200.

I just hope your GPU is replaceable; definitely want to research this before buying a replacement GPU; maybe even buy a better GPU :)